# Is it possible to use multiple helper (template) files in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

We are planning to use Helm to deploy the apps in k8s clusters.

We have set of standard definitions that are common across microservices and few definitions that are specific to each microservice.

Is it possible to define multiple (template) helper files so that common definitions are stored in one helper  (template) file and other definitions in a different  (template) helper file?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can use helper files. These helper file can be placed in a common or helper chart. This chart would only contain helper files and no templates that would be rendered. The microservice chart would then include the chart as a dependency.

Example of a common chart: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/common

Good article here which uses common chart example: https://medium.com/faun/dry-helm-charts-for-micro-services-db3a1d6ecb80